# How to save plot of live data on a remote machine?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know how my model is doing while it's training (i.e live data manner) by sshing and checking the plots.

Using the `animation.FuncAnimation` I'm able to make it save (& overwrite) a frame every time it updates on my local machine like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i):
    fig.clf()

    plt.suptitle('Title here')

    # actually parse model outputs and plot
    values = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, (100,))
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(values)), values, label='random')
    plt.ylabel('demo data')
    plt.grid()


    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    fig.savefig('Figure.png')


fig = plt.figure()
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10*60*1000)
plt.show()
```

Using this on a local machine is fine since the `plt.show` calls the $DISPLAY. However, when running on a remote server (via `ssh` of course) since there's no display, I get the `RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable`. When using other backends something like `svg` via `matplotlib.use('svg')`. The script exits without actually saving any image.

Also, my decision to use `plt.show()` and `fig.savefig('Figure.png')` inside the `animate` function were because without the `plt.show()` function after the call to `FuncAnimation`, it does NOT run the `animate` after given interval. I tried doing `plt.savefig` instead.

And regarding the `fig.savefig('Figure.png')`, doing so outside the `animate` function leads to a blank image. I'm guessing since I clear the image at the start of the `animate` function.

So, my question is: Is there a way to save figures generated on live data using `animation` (or `FuncAnimation`) like this over ssh till some event occurs (or perhaps a timeout)?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the webserver suggestion, you can use `watch` to run `scp` every `n` seconds and copy the png to your local machine.

Something like:

```
watch -n 5 scp user@remote:/path/to.png ./
```

which would copy the file every 5 seconds.

Or use `rsync` to only copy when it has actually changed. (There are also utilities that will use `scp` or `rsync` to copy it to your local machine when the file changes.)

Comment: Thanks, I already know this. I'm having issues generating (and updating) the png on the remote server. Perhaps try running this code on your local machine and then a remote machine to understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind "animation.FuncAnimation" is that an animating function is calling a function to write/update a fig.

You seems to want to generate the "png" file remotely and get it via SSH or some other way.

Sharing the "fig" between two machines doesn't work.

If you are running the "animate" function on a remote machine, move the
fig = plt.figure() into the function instead of the "fig.clf()"

```
def animate(i):
    fig = plt.figure()

....
```

While it's possible to write SSH code that connects to the remote machine, I'd probably run a simple webserver on the remote that serves each frame.

So that you could call
    http:///server_frame?index=i to load the frame.

If you're a beginner and there's no huge performance requirement, this can be done easily with cherrypy (https://cherrypy.org/). An example question on how to serve images is here: [How to serve multiple matplotlib images from cherrypy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104944/how-to-serve-multiple-matplotlib-images-from-cherrypy)

On the local side, you can now write a new "get_frame" function,
that downloads the frame and puts it onto a local fig.

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, get_frame, interval=10*60*1000)
```

Comment: I just want to save/update png on the remote server, which I can get by simply using scp/rsync. Your suggestion of moving the `fig = plt.figure()` inside the `animate` function won't work, since `animation.FuncAnimation` also needs `fig` as an argument.

Comment: Yes, you need a seperate fig for the local service **if** you want to Display the image locally. If you just want to load the file and not display it, you don't need animation at all. Here a simple loop with a time.wait(second) would be enough. BTW, "simply using scp/rsync" is not enough, you need to somehow trigger the remote machine to generate/update the image. One easy way to trigger is to serve it.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly doubt using the animation framework is the proper approach here. You could have it easier just saving the figure in your own loop and viewing it from ssh or exporting with scp.

Anyway, here's a workaround for your code.

First you need to use a backend that doesn't need a working `DISPLAY` (`mpl.use('Agg'`).

Then, I doubt the animation framework works at all in this scenario, it probably uses the graphics engine main loop for the drawing. You can use a `MovieWriter` though. Here I'm using a bare minimum movie writer that just saves the current frame in a png file.

Note that `interval` doesn't work in this case, it will save every frame you generate so you need to take care of the delay yourself in the generator (see the ugly `time.sleep(1)` below).

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                    

# headless backend
import matplotlib as mpl                                                                                                                                                              
mpl.use('Agg')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                       
import matplotlib.animation as animation                                                                                                                                              

import time                                                                                                                                                                           

# dummy movie writer                                                                                                                                                                                          
class NullMovieWriter(animation.AbstractMovieWriter):                                                                                                                                 
    """                                                                                                                                                                               
    from matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/tests/test_animation.py                                                                                                                            
    """                                                                                                                                                                               

    frame_size_can_vary = True                                                                                                                                                        

    def setup(self, fig, outfile, dpi, *args):                                                                                                                                        
        self.fig = fig                                                                                                                                                                
        self.outfile = outfile                                                                                                                                                        
        self.dpi = dpi                                                                                                                                                                
        self.args = args                                                                                                                                                              
        self._count = 0                                                                                                                                                               

    def grab_frame(self, **savefig_kwargs):                                                                                                                                           
        self.savefig_kwargs = savefig_kwargs                                                                                                                                          
        self._count += 1                                                                                                                                                              

        print("saving frame: {}".format(self._count))                                                                                                                                 
        self.fig.savefig(self.outfile)                                                                                                                                                

    def finish(self):                                                                                                                                                                 
        pass                                                                                                                                                                          



fig = plt.figure()                                                                                                                                                                    
def animate(i):                                                                                                                                                                       
    fig.clf()                                                                                                                                                                         

    plt.suptitle('Title here')                                                                                                                                                        

    # actually parse model outputs and plot                                                                                                                                           
    values = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, (100,))                                                                                                                                
    plt.plot(np.arange(len(values)), values, label='random')                                                                                                                          
    plt.ylabel('demo data')                                                                                                                                                           
    plt.grid()                                                                                                                                                                        


    plt.legend()                                                                                                                                                                      
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')                                                                                                                                                              

    time.sleep(1)                                                                                                                                                                     


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10*60*1000)                                                                                                                      
writer = NullMovieWriter()                                                                                                                                                            
ani.save("Figure.png", writer=writer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would be easier to save logs in plain text (or pickle) instead of rendering and every time you want to check how it's doing, just run a program on local machine that will download the data and plot it for you.

Or if you really want to render it on server side, then check out [MoviePy](https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/working_with_matplotlib.html) library which can easily integrate with matplotlib and render gifs for example.